# Why all android projects make errors in eclipse - ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu and my eclipse is getting errors every time i create a new project , I installed most of things from sdk and I tried to clean the project couple of times ,, but nothing happens , and solution ? 
[image]

and the conso;e message is :

```
    [2014-07-18 21:24:40 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/abdullah/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/jarlist.cache
```

Comment: Please provide details on the errors you are facing.

Comment: Screenshot indicates you have a problem finding the R class - a common issue amply covered in the linked question.  If you have other errors as well, edit their details into the question.

Comment: no , its not from the R its from ubuntu @Zeus

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim Do : Rightclick  Prject -> properties -> ANdroid. Select different android api level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same problem again and again then make sure you have installed the the latest platform tools. If you have installed all the tools then delete them and re-download. There could be a read/write access problem try to change the directory of your eclipse and android sdk tools.

Comment: see the new edit please